# Azure will be free with 5GB bandwidth and no database?

Tags: azure

I am using the  price calculator and select the website plan.

I drag the slide of bandwidth to 5GB, the price keep on $0.00.

So i wonder if i register a trial account for my ASP.NET website and keep the bandwidth usage under 5GB.

Is it mean i will not be charge forever after trial?

Any hidden fees i have to pay?

I have search on MSDN forum, but still not found the answer.

[image]

Comment: As long as your website is running under the *free* tier, it will remain free and you'll not be charged, even after your trial expires.

Comment: You can create up to 10 websites in a free mode. If you won't use Local Storage and no databases, it will be free. (at least they are not charging me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick to the Free tier, you won't have any additional charges.  Azure lists the details [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/).

The pricing calculator shows the 5GB bandwith as free since its based on monthly charge.  In the link you can see that the free tier offers outbound data transfer at 'up to 165MB per day' which works out to 5GB if you were to run at that everyday for a month.